# PHP - Days of the Week by Array

Tags: arrays

Here is my code:

```
$day = 1;

$dayList = array("0"=>"Sunday","1"=>"Monday");

if(in_array($day,$dayList)) {
    echo $dayList[$day];
}
```

I tried `$day = 0`, and it works good, but it doesn't work if string is `1`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`in_array()` checks values, not keys.  So in this instance it won't do what you want.  `isset()` is the function you need to use, try this:

```
if (isset($dayList[$day])) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_key_exists :

```
$day = 1;

$dayList = array("0"=>"Sunday","1"=>"Monday");

if(array_key_exists($day,$dayList)) {
    echo $dayList[$day];
}
```

More info:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Another method:
You could create a function that returns this value or the key like so:

```
function getDayOfTheWeek($name)
{

    $dayList = array("0"=>"Sunday","1"=>"Monday","2"=>"Tuesday","3" => "Wednesday");

    // if a string make sure it's capitalized
    if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $name)) {
        $name = ucwords(strtolower($name));
    } else {
        // if not a string flip the array and get name
        $dayList = array_flip($dayList);
    }

    return $dayList[$name];
}

// print results for each call to function
var_dump(getDayOfTheWeek('0')); // returns Sunday
var_dump(getDayOfTheWeek('1')); // returns Monday
var_dump(getDayOfTheWeek('Monday')); //returns 1
var_dump(getDayOfTheWeek('Tuesday')); // returns 2
```